# How to use HTML5 Canvas drawImage to put image slices into individual <div> elements?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, drawimage

I'm trying to take an image and slice it into 20 slices, and also have these slices appear in their own div's similar to below:

```
<div id="example" class="container">
  <div class="item slice1"></div>
  <div class="item slice2"></div>
  <div class="item slice3"></div>
  ...
</div>
```

I would prefer to have the images appear as background in CSS, though I can also make this work adding  inside the . A quick example I've found of slicing one image into multiple slices follows:

```
function drawOnCanvas() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("example");
   if (canvas.getContext){
    var canvas_context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("image");
      canvas_context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 180, 300, 20, 20, 150, 300);
      canvas_context.drawImage(img, 200, 0, 180, 300, 200, 20, 150, 300);
      canvas_context.drawImage(img, 350, 0, 180, 300, 380, 20, 150, 300);
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how to separate the slices contained within the canvas to either save them as slice1.jpg, slice2.jpg ... or something similar? Really stuck on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would modify the divs first (since they are unique we can might as well use id's which makes next step a bit easier):

```
<div id="example" class="container">
    <img id="slice0" class="item" src="" alt ="" />
    <img id="slice1" class="item" src="" alt ="" />
    <img id="slice2" class="item" src="" alt ="" />
 ...
</div>
```

Then in the code:

```
var i = 0,
    xPos = [0, 200, 350, ...];  //adjust to actual values

for(;i < xPos.length; i++) {
    canvas_context.drawImage(img, xPos[i], 0, 180, 300,  20, 20, 150, 300);
    var slice = canvas.toDataURL();

    var el = document.getElementById('slice' + i);
    el.src = slice;
}
```

This will create one slice at the time, extract it from canvas as a data-url and set the image source with the slice.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/GV8vW/5/